# SSL certificate for server authentication

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, tomcat, csr

to clear my understandings:
I create self signed certificate first

```
keytool -genkey -alias mysign -keyalg RSA -keystore mykeystorename.jks
```

the firstname of the self sign has to be my domain name?

Then I create the CSR

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias myCSR -file certreq.csr
    -keystore mykeystorename.jks
```

Is the self sign certificate called root certificate?

I give my CSR to CA(e.g. verisign).
In return Versign give me a certificate. Is that called intermediate certificate? Do CA provides private key too? Where do I get the private key?

Now, there is a REST API server. That server requires certificate to make calls. 
Me(client) needs to call his REST API, which certificate do I give him before calling the REST API?

When I make request to the REST API server which certificate do I give him now inside a keystore?

Can I use this certificate to test in local machine?

Comment: You created the private key when you created the cert. Look in that directory

Comment: @NeilSmithline: for Java it's not a separate file, it's an _entry_ in the keystore with type PrivateKeyEntry

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some misunderstandings.

If you make a certificate with a CA, they do *not* give you a private key. You have the PK of your certificate already, and the PK of the CA is secret.

With an self-signed certificate, you're acting as certificate holder *and* CA at the same time. Naturally, telling the people "I say that I'm thrustworthy" doesn't make you very thrustworthy.

If a REST API requires a certificate from the user, it's not meant for normal TLS, but (probably) as "login method", instead of a password. This type of certificates don't need CAs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is scattershot and not very clear so this can't be a complete answer

> the firstname of the self sign has to be my domain name?

**Only for SSL/TLS server -- mostly.**
What Java `keytool` prompts as `first and last name` is the **CommonName** attribute in the Subject name (also Issuer name for selfsigned). For SSL/TLS servers it **used to be required** that CommonName either *be* the domainname used by client(s) to access the server (since a server can have several domainnames but a given request/URL uses only one) or be a leftmost-only wildcard that *matches* the domainname used; the latter case is useful if you have several closely related servers like `sales.example.com` and `support.example.com` .

**Nowadays the SubjectAlternativeName extension** (abbreviated SubjectAltName or just SAN) is usually used instead; it can contain multiple entries and several types of entries (not just DNS, but DNS is used for SSL/TLS servers), and if present reliers *should* use it and ignore CommonName, but not all do so you should still set CommonName. For (Sun/Oracle) Java 7 or later you can use e.g. `-ext SAN=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com,DNS:www2.example.com`

For certificates (and keys) used for purposes **other than SSL/TLS servers**, the rules vary. It appears you want a key and certificate to authenticate a client to some REST API; it is not clear if this is in the SSL/TLS (possibly HTTPS) protocol or some other method. Depending on the protocol/method used, the needs of the server (and perhaps middleware the server uses), and the CA or CAs trusted by the server, they might want a domainname or something else.
However, in this case it may not matter what you put in the CSR, because the CA can change it to what they want.

> Is the self sign certificate called root certificate?

Not really. A root certificate is actually a kind of CA certificate, specifically one that issues (and is used to verify) other certificates, but is NOT itself issued by a higher-level CA; i.e. in a hierarchy of CAs it is at the top. (Unlike natural trees that have their roots in the ground, computer trees usually have their root -- and usually only one root -- at the top.) A root certificate is selfsigned, but not all selfsigned certs are truly root certs. However, even when a selfsigned cert is not actually a root it may still be handled by some software *as* a root because that's more convenient. To be clear, if you have a selfsigned cert for an end entity rather than a CA, you should call it selfsigned and not call it (a) root.

> I give my CSR to CA(e.g. verisign). In return Versign give me a certificate. Is that called intermediate certificate?

A public CA like Verisign-now-Symantec actually gives you *several* certificates, but only one of them is really 'yours'. This is because the root CA key (and cert) is much too valuable to be used for routine signing; instead it issues some (usually several) certificates to intermediate CAs, which are then used to issue end-entity certificates. This process may be extended to more than one intermediate level, but rarely if ever more than two.
See [Why is it more secure to use intermediate CA certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128779/why-is-it-more-secure-to-use-intermediate) and [Do I put my subordinate (intermediate) or root CA certificate in my truststore?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119460/do-i-put-my-subordinate-intermediate-or-root-ca-certificate-in-my-truststore)

Thus when you submit a CSR and prove your identity/authorization, the CA will **issue an end-entity certificate** with your identity and key, and provide that certificate. It will **also provide copies of the intermediate cert (or certs)** to be used *with* your cert, and possibly a copy of its root cert for completeness.
Depending on the CA (and perhaps your request) it may provide these certs together as a 'bundle' or 'chain', or it may provide them separately.

If you use a CA with significantly smaller scope, such as one run by the server's owner, they *may* skip the intermediate layer and just give you a cert issued by their root.

> Do CA provides private key too? Where do I get the private key?

[As already answered, no.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/124934/39571) You already generated the privatekey; that's what `-genkeypair` does. It's in your keystore file, and should remain there, protected by an adequately strong password.

> Now, there is a REST API server. That server requires certificate to make calls. Me(client) needs to call his REST API, which certificate do I give him before calling the REST API?
>   When I make request to the REST API server which certificate do I give him now inside a keystore?

First, be clear what this 'certificate' is for. If you are communicating over HTTPS (and thus SSL/TLS) your client needs to validate the server's certificate, and if the server is using a certificate that is not under a wellknown CA (including a selfsigned cert, which is not under *any* CA), then you need *their* root or anchor in your *truststore*. If you are communicating over HTTPS and they want to use SSL/TLS client authentication, you need a certificate AND PRIVATEKEY in your *keystore*, and that certificate needs to be issued by a CA the server's owner(s)/operator(s) trust, which might or might not include all wellknown CAs and might or might not include a CA they operate themselves. And if they want you to do some security method instead of or in addition to SSL/TLS, it depends what that is. All of these are different things, and might even exist in combination. Without details (or a reference that provides details) your questions are unanswerable.